# Compiling multiple C++ files. Calling a binary to run a code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have 2 cpp files(with one main function) in `/home/misha/proga/c++again` folder. I built `C/C++: g++ build active task` and modified it to compile all files in the folder above. Now, I need to add one more task to call a binary. I think I should add one more entry in `"tasks"` to finally be able to run a code. Where can I read about how to  write this second task? I am new to programming. Is my approach correct to run this code contained in two files? I also do not know where this binary lies. Is it `tasks` file in `.vscode` folder ?

I use Ubuntu 19.10 and VSC 1.46.1

Comment: There should be some documentation on this topic, since this question is asked repeatedly. I've yet to find it however.

Comment: If you want to debug the program you need to create a "launch.json" file, as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_debug-helloworldcpp Otherwise I'm not entirely sure why you want to have a task to launch the compiled code, but you could always create a separate on in the tasks.json. And the binary file should be wherever you specified it should be output to in your build task

Comment: For an example of a task that starts another program check the Custom Tasks section of the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

Comment: Read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and use a build automation tool (perhaps [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal,

```
cd /home/misha/proga/c++again
```

Let's suppose your two cpp files are `mainFile.cpp` and `file2.cpp`

If g++ (so [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) was not installed in your system, you can install it by running this command on the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++
```

and, to compile the program (read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), you want warnings and debug information), write this command into the Terminal:

```
g++ -Wall -g mainFile.cpp file2.cpp -o yourprog
```

Then, you can run the program by typing:

```
./yourprog
```

It should work now. You could need to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)  (to be installed with `sudo apt-get install gdb make`)

Read also some [C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) C++ reference.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your approach usualy your create a makefile and compile your cpp files
g++ -g -c -fpic -o name.o
at the end you link them
g++ name.o 2name.o and so on
If you create binarys you should store them in /usr/lib
and the name should libname.so you can acces them by using the -l argument